# How to set an alias for "npm innit" in Mac OS X terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, npm

This is a "fun" question with some level of serious application. I like chav lingo and I was thinking it would be pretty cool to run `npm innit` instead of `npm init`. I know broadly npm allows aliases through package.json (eg when you run scripts) eg `npm run innit` would be trivial. however that's not really what I'm going for. I want to alias `npm innit` to `npm init`. just wondering if theres a way. i've looked through `npm help` as well as `.bash_profile alias` instructions on macosx but they dont really allow for space-separated aliases...

please let me know if you have any ideas. would help me learn aliasing more generally too.

thank you.

Comment: I would define a function for this. According to the bash manual: *For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.* :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

> If the last character of the alias value is a *blank*, then the next
>   command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

So you can do this:

```
alias npm='npm ' # The trailing space is important
alias innit='init'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following alias for npm cmd

```
alias nib="npm i && npm run bootstrap"
alias nb="npm run bootstrap"
alias ncib="npm run clean && npm i && npm run bootstrap"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this alias is already defined in NPM by default, and has been at least since [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57133248/16781396) was posted in 2019, and is now [documented](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-init) in the v8.x docs.

```
npm init <package-spec> (same as `npx <package-spec>)
npm init <@scope> (same as `npx <@scope>/create`)
```

`aliases: create,`**innit**

I believe this is just in case people misspell `init`, though it's possible that it was added as a humorous thought by the NPM devs.