# What is the 'npm create' command?

Tags: npm, npm-init

As the [UmiJS documentation](https://github.com/umijs/create-umi) suggests, a project is created with the `npm create` command:

```
npm create umi
```

It seems to be working, but it's not documented.

Why did it appear and when? Is it a full synonym for `npm init`? Is there a reason why `npm create` should or should not be used?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It is an interesting question; I wasn't aware of this either.

To answer this question, I ran

```
npm create --help
```

which printed

> npm init [--force|-f|--yes|-y|--scope] npm init <@scope> (same as `npx <@scope>/create`) npm init [<@scope>/] (same as `npx [<@scope>/]create-<name>`)
>
> aliases: create, innit

So yes, it is a synonym, or more specifically an alias, for `npm init`.

This was done using npm 6.10.1.

It doesn't matter which command one uses, but `init` is the canonical form while `create` is an alias. This is evidenced by the fact that `npm create --help` actually invokes `npm init --help` which is why we see `create` listed as an alias in this above output.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I suspect this could be done to be coherent with `yarn create startername` usage but I haven't noticed before that both managers cared too much about compatibility.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes, I suspect it's there for discoverability reasons. Actually, I just looked at Yarn and `create` and `init` are _not_ synonymous.

Comment: Yes, it looks that Yarn separated them for some reason, similarly to install/add.

Answer (score 30):

`npm create xyz` is actually an undocumented shorthand for:

`npx create-xyz`

In other words, it prepends "create-" to the package name, temporarily installs that package, and then runs the script defined in the `package.json`. This is used by several projects. For the `umi` project, it implies there is a `create-umi` package as well, and as you can see there is:

*[create-umi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-umi)*

This is what the command is downloading and executing. Specifically it is executing the script defined in its *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file:

```json
  "bin": {
    "create-umi": "bin/create-umi.js"
  },
```

Many frameworks follow this pattern so you can use the command. Some others:

- [Svelte](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-svelte): `npm create svelte@latest`
- [Vue.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-vue): `npm create vue@latest`
- [React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app): `npm init react-app my-app`

Answer (score 1):

**npm create** is a shorter way to use a tool that sets up a new project quickly. e.g:  **npm create umi** creates a new project using the **umi** framework for building web applications. It saves time by generating a basic project structure and installing any necessary dependencies.

While **npm init** creates a new package.json file for a project, it does not generate a basic project structure.
**npm create** is a user-friendly alternative that automates the process of setting up a new project.
**npm create** is a useful shortcut for setting up a new project quickly, but it's important to note that not all Node.js packages support it.
like : **express**

Comment: No, `npm create` is just an alias, as listed [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/b1c3256d62250b5dca113dd99bf1bd99f2500318/lib/utils/cmd-list.js#L95C18-L95C18)