# How can I compile a svelte component into a one line import for a pure HTML application?

Tags: javascript, svelte, cdn, svelte-component, script-tag

I have a svelte component that someone else wants to use on their own website, which is pure HTML/JavaScript.

My plan is for them to use a script tag referencing a cdn I host, like this:

`<script src="http://examplecdn.com/myfile.js"></script>`

Do I need to setup the project in a certain way to facilitate this? How do I find the file for the specific component? I can create a new project with just this component, but don't want to have to convert the code away from svelte.

---

For some context, for testing I have set up a basic svelte project with:

`npm create svelte@latest my-example-module`

And have just added this code to test if I can get something simple working:

```
<script lang="ts">
    let text = "IT IS WORKING"
</script>
<h1>{text}</h1>
<style>
    h1 {font-size: 3rem}
</style>
```

I ran `npm run build`, and have a lot of compiled javascript, but am not sure what a next step would be.

Comment: My guess is that the exported JS object or objects are defined by how this other person wants to consume it.  For example, maybe you just export the Svelte component class, and then the consumer is responsible for instantiating, mounting and unmounting the component.  Or maybe this person is using `single-spa` or a similar architecture that imposes requirements on what the module must export.  Etc.  Bottom line:  Ask this other person how he/she intends to consume your component.

Answer (score 1):

The svelte team is really pushing users to use sveltekit, and for a certain type of project that might be the way to go, but IMHO in many cases another approach might be better suited and much simpler.

You can try these steps instead:

start the project using vite and select svelete template

```s
npm init vite
```

I selected these options

```
Need to install the following packages:
  create-vite
Ok to proceed? (y) y
√ Project name: ... vite-project
√ Select a framework: » Svelte
√ Select a variant: » JavaScript
```

Then you need to edit the `vite.config.js` file and add build options

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { svelte } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";
import { resolve } from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        format: "iife",
        dir: resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
        entryFileNames: "main.js",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I set to IIFE, but you can use any other format (es, cjs, umd etc) note that the default is setup to use modules, so you need to import it using `type="module"` :

```html
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing, but the `npm create svelte` command *([i.e.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76870223/1026) the `create-svelte` npm package)* creates a **SvelteKit** app, which (as of 2023-09) [does not support your use-case out-of-the-box](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2572).

You can instead [use a svelte-only template, as suggested by Daniel here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76293603/1026) or (once you start feeling comfortable with all this) [add a custom vite config to a SvelteKit skeleton, as in this recipe](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/10320) for a svelte->webcomponent library.

The way you include svelte components in a pure HTML / vanilla JS page depends on how you build the components:

- The arguably easier way is to output "web components" (as detailed in this [only slightly outdated tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-web-components-svelte/#building-your-web-components):

  - Put `<svelte:options customElement="my-card" />` on top of the component's `.svelte` file
  - Put `compilerOptions: {  customElement: true, ...` wherever they're specified in your setup
  - Include the produced JS bundle in your HTML via `<script>`
  - Use the custom element in your HTML: `<my-card></my-card>`
- In the regular mode svelte produces JS classes which must be bound to the DOM elements manually ([Client-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api))

---

To elaborate on SvelteKit vs Svelte starter templates:

`npm run build` in a SvelteKit app builds the site, including the server and client JS for all pages (`src/routes/*`) (see [Project structure](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/project-structure)).

As the [official documentation on packaging](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging) puts it:

> A component library has the exact same structure as a SvelteKit app, except that src/lib is the public-facing bit, and your root package.json is used to publish the package. src/routes might be a documentation or demo site that accompanies the library, or it might just be a sandbox you use during development.

If you select "Library project" in create-svelte:

```
create-svelte version 5.0.5

┌  Welcome to SvelteKit!
│
◇  Where should we create your project?
│  test
│
◆  Which Svelte app template?
│  ○ SvelteKit demo app
│  ○ Skeleton project
│  ● Library project (Barebones scaffolding for your new Svelte library)
└
```

...you'll end up with a slightly different setup, which [includes](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/a58f0491ecbd91cc3729836b6940066b1ee7317c/packages/create-svelte/templates/skeletonlib/package.template.json#L8,L24) a `@sveltejs/package` devDependency and a `npm run package` script, which runs `svelte-package` to build the components from the `src/lib` directory to a `dist/` folder.

This gives you an npm package you can publish and/or install *in other svelte apps*, as it still contains `.svelte` files and relies on the destination app having a build step. There's https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2572 which proposes to extend svelte-package to produce JS bundle, which can be used in non-svelte apps.

But svelte projects not using the kit (e.g. started using the now-deprecated [sveltejs/template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) or the newer create-vite [svelte template](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/create-vite/template-svelte)) do not even have the "app" part, so their build step is much closer to what you need.

---